# Denoise for animations on laptop with CPU only in Blender 3?

Tags: animation, denoise

I'm trying to make some simple animations of stuff imported from Minecraft. I have an MB Pro from 2019, so no GPU that will be of any use. Denoise for images works super well, even with images rendered (in cycles) with really low sample counts like 20. However, when put in animations there is crazy flickering going on.

From what I've gathered, I need temporal denoise but I can't get that working. I've tried Super Image Denoiser, but the temporal mode doesn't work (and says it's obsolete). Rendering to exr multilayer and denoising with bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation(input_filepath='', output_filepath='') does nothing (it just says FINISHED but never outputs any files, regardless of whether i point to a folder or make a loop feeding it with each exr iteratively).

Any other options? Other denoiser? Skip denoiser and increase samples, light clamping?

Comment: When you say you used ```bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation(input_filepath='', output_filepath='')```, you did put actual file paths inside the quotation marks after "input_filepath" and "output_filepath"?

Comment: Yes, I both tried with a directory as input (/usr/me/rendered) and with files in a loop

```myfiles=(glob.glob("*.exr"))
for file in myfiles:

   bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation(input_filepath=(inputdir + file), output_filepath=(outputdir + file))
```

(sorry about the indentation, don't know how to get that right :-) )

Comment: Yeah, i also tried it on my end the way I used to do it a while ago and it doesn't seem to work either.... That being said, the more work you leave to the denoising, the more inconsistent it is. So pushing up the sample count should at least lessen the issue.

Comment: I also tried in 2.93 anbd 2.83 but then it thinks my EXR have no denoising data (maybe EXR from 3.0 are different, but I don't have time to render from 2.83). Also make sure you do NOT [Use Animater Seed](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html?highlight=%22Use%20Animated%20Seed%20%22#advanced)

Comment: Tried with a lot higher sample count and that did, as you said, fix it. Good and bad news since my computer is so slow at rendering :-). A simple minecraft animation of 180 frames at unimpressive resolution: 11 hours :-/